# set up a user and its root dir in vsftpd, in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vsftpd

I want to setup a `www-data` user for vsftpd and set its root dir to `/somepath/www-data/project`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vsftpd man page is [here](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd/vsftpd_conf.html). Also check out the [example directory](ftp://vsftpd.beasts.org/users/cevans/untar/vsftpd-3.0.0/EXAMPLE/) showing different possible FTP configurations.

### Real users

Assuming you want a real system user to access ftp, you will have to set the option **local_enable=Yes**. But if you do that, all your users will automatically be able to log in via FTP. Therefore it might be a good idea to setup a whitelist of FTP users by setting **userlist_enable=Yes**, **userlist_deny=No** and specifying '**userlist_file**'. If you wish to lock users in their home directories, you can set **chroot_local_user=Yes**

minimal sample /etc/vsftpd.conf:

```
# Access rights
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.user_list
write_enable=YES
```

### Virtual Users

Vsftpd also supports virtual users via PAM integration. Set **guest_enable=Yes** in /etc/vsftpd.conf. This has the effect of mapping every non-anonymous successful login to the local username specified in  '**guest_username**'. Then, use PAM and (e.g.) its pam_userdb module to provide authentication against an external (i.e. non-/etc/passwd) repository of users.
I've never personally used this configuration, but there are examples of virtual users setups in the [example directory](ftp://vsftpd.beasts.org/users/cevans/untar/vsftpd-3.0.0/EXAMPLE/).

Answer (score 0):

First log in as root:  sudo -i.
Then to add a user:  useradd -d /somepath/www-data/project -m user

That user should then be able to log in.